# How to search data from related table in yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

Hi guys i am trying to search data using $searchModel in a view file and having problem displaying and searching related table.

Here is my `SearchModel` where `clubname` is related data from `organiser` table and i am trying to search it in `Event` form.

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['title', 'description', 'location', 'clubname'], 'safe'],
    ];

}

public function search($params)
{
    $query = Event::find();

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);

    $this->load($params);

    $query->joinWith(['organiser']);

    if (!$this->validate()) {
        // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
        // $query->where('0=1');
        return $dataProvider;
    }

    $query->andFilterWhere([
        'id' => $this->id,
        'interest_id' => $this->interest_id,
    ]);

    $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'title', $this->title])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'description', $this->description])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'location', $this->location]);
    $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'organiser.clubname', $this->organiser_id]);

    return $dataProvider;
}
```

Here is my `$search` page and list below it

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
        'action' => ['index'],
        'method' => 'get',
    ]); ?>

    <div class="row">
    <?= $form->field($searchModel, 'title',[
        'template' => ' <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-3">{label}</div><div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-8">{input}</div>'
    ])->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($searchModel, 'clubname',[
        'template' => ' <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-3">{label}</div><div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-8">{input}</div>'
    ])->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton('Search', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-xs']) ?>
        <?= Html::resetButton('Reset', ['class' => 'btn btn-default btn-xs']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

There is no problem in search for `title` but i want user to also be able to search using `clubname` which is field in `Organiser` table and they have relation with `id`.

Comment: You need to manually add attributes to `SearchModel` then it will be easy to find the data.

Comment: @InsaneSkull i did. I have updated the question. But it gives me error on view page of unknow property for clubname

Comment: you have to add `relation_name.property` and also `attribute()` function.

Comment: @InsaneSkull I have added the `relation_name.property` function which you can see in the last `$query->andFilterWhere` but i dont know how to add `attribute()` function.

Comment: You can declare one public variable in `model` named `clubname` for your view and do above step for search results .

Comment: Use :  `public function attributes() { return array_merge(parent::attributes(), [ 'organiser.clubName', ]);}`

Comment: You are filtering data instead of searching. so, what do you actually want to do?

Comment: @InsaneSkull i want to search data and return dataprovider according to that. I could easily do that for `title` field because its in the same table. All i did was to display search button and `title` field. Just like that i want to implement search using a related field

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96514/discussion-between-insane-skull-and-mike-ross).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `RelationName.property` in `searchModel`:

```
public function rules()
{

return [
    [['title', 'description', 'location', 'organiser.clubname'], 'safe'],
];

}
```

Then add `attributes()` function :

```
public function attributes() 
{ 
  return array_merge(parent::attributes(), 
  [ 
    'organiser.clubname', 
  ]
  );
}
```

And Finally add query to search data:

```
$query->andWhere(['Attribute_name' => $params['attribute']]);
```

Comment: should i just check the value `isset` or not for null values? or you use any other approach?